# Spatial Filter in Qgis Using Python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, python-2.7

Is it possible to create buffer and get intersected features in Qgis using Python?

I did in ArcObjects.but i need the same in QGIS also.

```
Dim topo As ITopologicalOperator
topo = chkPoint
Dim sFc As ISpatialFilter = New SpatialFilter
With sFc
  .Geometry = topo.Buffer(1000)
  .GeometryField = "Shape"
  .SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelIntersects
  .WhereClause = "NAME = 'ROYAL'"
End With
pFcursor = pLayer.Search(sFc, False)
pFeature = pFcursor.NextFeature
```

Comment: Sure, everything you can do in QGIS desktop can be reproduced in Python using the pyqgis api... Have you explored the QGis plugin system? http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/plugins.html

Comment: Is chkPoint a single point? (Never used ArcObjects)

Comment: @Nathan yes its a single point

Comment: @Etienne yes i have developed few QGIS plugins.

Comment: Which version of QGIS?

Comment: QGIS 1.9 Master